# awk splitting into two fields in output

Tags: awk

The below `awk` inserts `inheritance` in `$10` and defaults the value in each line to `.` The problem is that it seems to be splitting the old `$10` into two separate fields causing the data to shift.

For example, `$10` bedore the `awk` was `nonsynonymous SNV` in and after it is split into two columns and I am not sure why or how to fix it.

**file**

```
R_Index Chr Start   End Ref Alt Func.IDP.refGene    Gene.IDP.refGene    GeneDetail.IDP.refGene  ExonicFunc.IDP.refGene  AAChange.IDP.refGene
1   chr1    949608  949608  G   A   exonic  ISG15   .   nonsynonymous SNV   ISG15:NM_005101.3:exon2:c.248G>A:p.S83N
22  chr1    1650845 1650845 G   A   intergenic  DVL1,GABRD  dist=366353;dist=299923 .   .
23  chr1    1957037 1957037 T   C   exonic  GABRD   .   synonymous SNV  GABRD:NM_000815.4:exon4:c.330T>C:p.G110G
```

**current output**

```
R_Index Chr Start   End Ref Alt Func.IDP.refGene    Gene.IDP.refGene    GeneDetail.IDP.refGene  Inheritence ExonicFunc.IDP.refGene  AAChange.IDP.refGene
1   chr1    949608  949608  G   A   exonic  ISG15   .   .   nonsynonymous   SNV ISG15:NM_005101.3:exon2:c.248G>A:p.S83N
22  chr1    1650845 1650845 G   A   intergenic  DVL1,GABRD  dist=366353;dist=299923 .   .   .
23  chr1    1957037 1957037 T   C   exonic  GABRD   .   .   synonymous  SNV GABRD:NM_000815.4:exon4:c.330T>C:p.G110G
```

**awk**

```
awk '{$10=NR==1?"Inheritence" OFS $10:"." OFS $10} 1' OFS="\t" file > output
```

edit `awk` print

```
awk '{print $11}' output
ExonicFunc.IDP.refGene
nonsynonymous
.
synonymous

awk '{print $12}' output
AAChange.IDP.refGene
SNV
.
SNV
```

Comment: not sure what exactly you think is going wrong...  you can check particular columns like `awk '{print $11}' output` .. is spacing your issue?

Comment: I added an edit showing that what was in `$10` before the `awk` is now in two fields... it may be spacing not sure.  Thank you :).

Comment: `awk '{print $11}' output` is exactly matching `awk '{print $10}' file` when I tried...

Comment: yea i get that to, but after I run the `awk` the columns are shifted.... is there a way to tell `awk` not to interpret the space in `nonsynonymous SNV'  the '$10' as a new field?  Thank you :).

Comment: hopefully the program that generates `output` is using the tab char as the field separator? If so, you may must need to tell awk with `awk -F'\t' '{program}' output` . And to use tab as output, you want `awk -F'\t'  -v OFS='\t' '{program}' output` . This is why using `|` or other visible character that is not in data is a good think for using as `FS`. Good luck.

Comment: That was it @shellter... thank you very much :).

Comment: this might help as well... `sed -r -e '1 s/^(\S+\s+){9}/\0Inheritence\t/' -e '2,$ s/^(\S+\s+){9}/\0.\t/' file > output` ... in the replacement section, you can use literal spaces instead of `\t` if needed.. this solution doesn't care what was in column 10 and later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution using `GNU sed`

```
sed -r -e '1 s/^(\S+\s+){9}/\0Inheritence\t/' -e '2,$ s/^(\S+\s+){9}/\0.\t/' file > output
```

- Capture group is used here repeated by a count to specify number of columns - in this case first 9 columns
- `\0` contains the entire matched text
- The first substitute acts on 1st line while the second one acts from 2nd line to last line.

**Edit**: can be simplified to

```
sed -E '1s/[^ \t]+/Inheritence\t&/10; 2,$s//.\t&/10'
```

- `[^ \t]+` other than space/tab characters
- `10` replace 10th occurrence
- the second regex will reuse `[^ \t]+` for the empty match section
- I think this would work for other than `GNU sed` versions too